# C++ - MQ RC Code 2219

Tags: c++, multithreading, ibm-mq

I got a rc code 2219, the design of the program is we have 2 threads. One for getting messages and one for putting/sending messages to the queue. So we got 2 processes running simultaneously.

> `Here's the flow of get thread:`
>
> *connect to queue manager
>
> *set connection reference/listener
>
> *set get message option (wait indefinitely)
>
> *open queue
>
> *get message from queue
>
> `Here's the flow of put thread:`
>
> *connect to queue manager
>
> *set connection reference/listener
>
> *set put message option
>
> *open queue
>
> *put message to queue

- `get` - will connect to queue manager, opens the queue and has a loop of getting messages indefinitely. (wait interval is set to unlimited, mqgmo_wait).
- `put` - will connect to the same queue manager, opens the queue and will put messages to other queue. We got an error on put while opening the queue with rc code 2219.

Do you guys have any suggestion on how to address the rc code?

Comment: `MQRC 2219` means that application attempted to execute an MQ API call while another MQ API is already under execution on the same connection. It appears that both get and put threads are using the same connection.

What connect options are you using? MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_NO_BLOCK? Can you post your code?

Comment: The 2219 code means `MQRC_CALL_IN_PROGRESS` which usually indicates a threading problem.  So when you say "We got an error on put while opening the queue" which is it?  An error on the `OPEN` or an error on the `PUT`?  Or are you using `PUT1` which does all of these things in one call?  Are you by any chance reusing the connection handle on either the QMgr or queue?  Which of the things in the [2219 manual entry](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q042560_.htm?lang=en) have you investigated and ruled out?

Comment: This is almost undoutedly a thread management problem. But without additional detail, it is impossible to diagnose. Voting to close as too vague.  Add more detail and I'll rescind my vote.  Leave the question as-is and risk closure by additional voters.

Comment: There is a problem with the PUT. Anyway I already resolved the issue, I added a C code sleep(); to atleast give time the PUT to do it's task, and I have not getting the rc code 2219 since then.

Comment: So, basically, you have thread contention and resolved it by tweaking the timing to make collisions less likely.  This will probably test well but how it behaves in a busy QMgr is another matter altogether.  If it craps out in Production and you decide to tackle the thread management issues, feel free to come back and provide the detail requested in the initial comments.