# multithreading with MQ

Tags: multithreading, perl, ibm-mq

I'm having problem using [MQSeries](https://metacpan.org/pod/MQSeries) Perl module in multi-threading environment. Here what I have tried:

- create two handle in different thread with `$mqMgr = MQSeries::QueueManager->new()`. I thought this would give me two different connection to MQ, but instead I got return code 2219 on the second call to `MQOPEN()`, which probably means I got the same underling connection to mq from two separate call to new() method.
- declare only one $mqMgr as global **shared** variable. But I can't assign reference to an MQSeries::QueueManager object to `$mqMgr`. The reason is *"Type of arg 1 to threads::shared::share must be one of [$@%] (not subroutine entry)"*
- declare only one `$mqMgr` as global variable. Got same 2219 code.
- Tried to pass  `MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_NO_BLOCK` into `MQSeries::QueueManager->new()`, so that a single connection can be shared across thread. But I can not find a way to pass it in.

My question is, with Perl module MQSeries

- How/can I get separate connection to MQ queue manager from different thread?
- How/can I share a connection to MQ queue manager across different thread?

I have looked around but with little luck, Any info would be appreciated.

related question:

- [C++ - MQ RC Code 2219](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091129/c-mq-rc-code-2219)

---

Update 1: add a example that two local MQSeries::QueueManager object in two thread cause MQ error code 2219.

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use MQSeries;
use MQSeries::QueueManager;
use MQSeries::Queue;

# globals
our $jobQ = Thread::Queue->new();
our $resultQ = Thread::Queue->new();

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# sub routines
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

sub worker {
    # fetch work from $jobQ and put result to $resultQ
    # ...
}

sub monitor {
    # fetch result from $resultQ and put it onto another MQ queue
    my $mqQMgr = MQSeries::QueueManager->new( ... );

    # different queue from the one in main
    # this would cause error with MQ code 2219
    my $mqQ = MQSeries::Queue->new( ... );

    while (defined(my $result = $resultQ->dequeue())) {
        # create an mq message and put it into $mqQ
        my $mqMsg = MQSeries::Message->new();
        $mqQ->put($mqMsg);
    }   
}

# main
unless (caller()) {
    # create connection to MQ
    my $mqQMgr = MQSeries::QueueManager->new( ... );
    my $mqQ = MQSeries::Queue->new( ... );

    # create worker and monitor thread
    my @workers;
    for (1 .. $nThreads) {
        push(@workers, threads->create('worker'));
    }
    my $monitor = threads->create('monitor');

    while (True) {
        my $mqMsg = MQSeries::Message->new ();

        my $retCode = $mqQ->get(
            Message => $mqMsg,
            GetMsgOptions => $someOption,
            Wait => $sometime
        );

        die("error") if ($retCode == 0);
        next if ($retCode == -1); # no message

        # not we have some job to do
        $jobQ->enqueue($mqMsg->Data);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to include some sample code - an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for example.

Comment: @Sobrique thanks for the suggestion, example added.

Comment: OK. Just noticed that mqseries does some registry stuff if on win32

Answer (score 2):

There is a very real danger when trying to multithread with modules that the module is not thread safe. There's a bunch of things that *can* just break messily because of the way threading works - you clone the current process state, and that includes things like file handles, sockets, etc.

But if you try and *use* them in an asynchronous/threaded way, they'll act *really* weird because the operations aren't (necessarily) atomic.

So whilst I can't answer your question directly, because I have no experience of the particular module:

Unless you know otherwise, assume you *can't* share between threads. It might be thread safe, it might not. If it isn't, it might still *look* ok, until one day you get a horrifically difficult to find bug as a result of a race condition in concurrent conditions.

A shared scalar/list is explicitly described in `threads::shared` as basically safe (and even then, you can still have problems with non-atomicity if you're not locking).

I would suggest therefore that what you need to do is either:

- have a 'comms' thread, that does *all* the work related to the module, and make the other threads use IPC to talk to it. `Thread::Queue` can work nicely for this.
- treat each thread as entirely separate for purposes of the module. That includes loading it (with `require` and `import` - not `use` because that acts earlier) and instantiating. (You *might* get away with 'loading' the module before threads start, but instantiating does things like creating descriptors, sockets etc.)
- lock stuff when there's any danger of interruption of an atomic operation.

Much of the above also applies to `fork` parallelism too - but not in quite the same way, as `fork` makes "sharing" stuff considerably harder, so you're less likely to trip over it.

Edit:

Looking at the code you've posted, and crossreferencing against the `MQSeries` source:

- There is a `BEGIN` block, that sets up some stuff with the MQSeries at the point at which you `use` it.

Whilst I can't say for sure that this is your problem, it makes me very wary - because bear in mind that when it does that, it sets up some stuff - and then when your threads start, they inherit non-shared copies of "whatever it did"  during that "BEGIN" block.

So in light of what I suggested earlier on - I would recommend you *try* (because I can't say for sure, as I don't have a reference implementation):

```
require MQSeries; 
MQSeries->import;
```

Put this in your code - in lieu of `use` - *after* thread start. E.g. after you do the `creates` and *within* the thread subroutine.